# Trouble with the 'or' operator with strings in Python 3.2

Tags: python, string, operators, python-3.2

I'm having some serious issues with getting the 'or' operator to work with strings in python 3.2

My code is similar to this:

```
   def choose_colour():

    cmd = input("Enter command here: ")

    if cmd != ("green") or ("blue") or ("yellow"):

        choose_colour()

    if cmd == ("green"):

        colour = ("g")

    if cmd == ("blue"):

        colour = ("b")

    if cmd == ("yellow"):

        colour = ("y")

    print (colour)

choose_colour()
```

However if I enter either one of these colours or not, it still repeats the 'choose_colour' function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you indenting properly, sorry for asking it's just that from the code above I cannot be sure.

Comment: yeah, it's all indented correctly (im not too sure how to indent on this website)

Comment: In which case you have probelm?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use `!=` for three condition you should apply `!=` to all of them :

```
if cmd != ("green") or cmd != ("blue") or cmd != ("yellow"):
```

In Python we cant use `!=` operator as you used in question . For example see here :

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 1
if a == c or b:
    print ("ok")  # it will print ok how ever conditions a==b==c not satisfied
```

Because the conditions here checking is `a == c` and `b==True` not `a==c` and `a==b`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference, still does the same as before.

Comment: @solluu add a sample input output into your question , so we can help you better

Comment: ive edited the question now

Comment: Please edit your indentation , I dont understand where fucntion ends

Comment: sorry about that, took me a while how to indent on this website

Comment: @Arman, The first two examples are equivalent.   If cmd = 'green', or example, the first compound condition will evaluate to true since it is True that cmd != 'blue' while it will evaluate to False in the second.

Comment: @GarrettR I didn't get what you mean

Comment: Try assigning 'green' to cmd.  And then evaluate the two conditions that you present:  if cmd != ("green") or cmd != ("blue") or cmd != ("yellow"): and if cmd not in ["green","blue","yellow"]:  They return different answers.

Comment: @GarrettR Yeah , thats true my fault